# How can I get random ID of element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation, the id always change for a random one,
so I can't use find_element_by_id

have some `divs` above,

```
<div class="x-tree-view  x-fit-item x-tree-view-default x-unselectable" 
id="treeview-2234" 
tabindex="0" 
componentid="componentstree-1118"
 style="overflow: auto; 
margin: 0px; height: 443px; width: 228px;">


<div class="x-grid-item-container"
 style="width: 228px;
 transform: 
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

<table id="treeview-2234-record-879" 
       data-boundview="treeview-2234" 
       data-recordid="879" 
       data-recordindex="0" 
       class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" 
       cellpadding="0" 
       cellspacing="0" 
       style="width:100%;">
```

I already tried:

- Use recordid, but sometimes the recordid repeats.
- By class_name, but sometimes the class repeats.
- OF course by id, but as I've already said, when page refreshes, it becomes another id
- By treeview-2234 root...fail

I'm another victim of `EXt`, what can I do?

Comment: Well, you have to find some way to identify the element by some combination of class, node type, other attributes, position in DOM, contents. Only you know how your page is structured.

Comment: Sounds like you could go the `xPath` route.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'x-grid-item-container']/table[contains(@data-boundview,'treeview-')]")

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is different each time the page is refreshed then it is impossible to select the element by ID. Instead, you need to find a way to select the element by something else which is unique. This could be by using one of the attributes (`data-boundview`, `data-recordid`,....), or by selecting the path to the `table` element via the HTML structure which is loaded whenever the page is refreshed.

I would then use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` to select the element. For example, you could select the element by attribute as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@data-boundview="treeview-2234"]')
```

Alternatively, if you know the HTML structure, you could do something along the following lines:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="ancestor-div"]/div[@id="parent-div"]/table')
```

Comment: i try by xpath, but when page refresh treeview-2234 turns, treeview-3746
i will try by html sctructure

Comment: Is there any attribute that remains the same when you refresh the page? Perhaps `data-recordid="879"`?

Comment: still, but i have another structure with the same id record,

Comment: Then post more html code and let us understand the scenario- better web page link.

Comment: If all else fails you can resort to selecting using indexes in your `XPath` eg `'//div/div[2]/table[1]'`

Comment: That HTML isn't particularly complete - hard to answer without closing tags etc

Answer (score 1):

I would try **xpath**  on the dom as expected. You may need to grab the **not changing parent dom** of the **changing dom** and get inside child from it by many ways esp in xpath-

Use `contains` function-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'x-grid-item-container']/table[contains(@data-boundview,'treeview-')]")
```

It will grab all `data-boundview` that has value starts with `treeview-` If there are more `data-boundview` with value starts with `treeview-` then try to grab **non-changing parent** first  and then dig into it to get child as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible...Return this message

Comment: Ah! use wait before using xpath e.g. `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` for waiting 10 seconds.

Comment: Try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@data-boundview,'treeview-')]")` it should return a list.

Answer (score 1):

if ur id changes randomly, use the unchanged classes, like below:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.x-tree-view.x-fit-item.x-tree-view-default.x-unselectable");
```

this will select the first div.To choose second div, use

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.x-grid-item-container");
```

if the table is under this div, try like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.x-grid-item-container>table.x-grid-item.x-grid-item-selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id="treeview-2234"` is constant in your id, you can search for id which contains it:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*="treeview-2234"]');
```